# AWS IOS SDK DynamoDB Scan - Thread de scan funciona no emulador, mas não ao debugar no dispositivo

Tags: ios, amazon-aws, sdk

No meu app faço uso de um scan com o DynamoDB que funciona perfeitamente no emulador para todas versões de iOS que o xCode disponibiliza, entretanto, ao debugar no dispositivo (iPhone 5c), não executa a thread principal.

```
[[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[DDBTableRow class]
                  expression:scanExpression]
      continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
//Execução da Thread principal          
.
.
.
return nil;
  }] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
      if (task.error) {
          NSLog(@"refreshList Error");
      }
      return nil;
  }];
```

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido atualizando o pod  (AWSiOSSDKv2 2.0.17 (was 2.0.13)).
Mais detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951973/aws-ios-sdk-dynamodb-scan-mainthread-works-in-emulador-but-dont-in-device-de/29115231#29115231

Comment: Se você encontrou a resposta para sua dúvida favor marcar como respondida.